# Snowflake how to accommodate an unparseable JSON row

Tags: json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Suppose this query

```
select gestimate, (get(parse_json(gestimate) :duration,'value')) / 60.0  AS rc_estimate 
from mytable;
```

blows up because 120M rows in, there is an unparseable row.  How to adjust this query so it places a 0 into rc_estimate if it is unparseable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [TRY_PARSE_JSON](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/try_parse_json.html):

```
select gestimate, (get(try_parse_json(gestimate) :duration,'value')) / 60.0  AS rc_estimate 
from mytable;
```

`COALESCE(expr, 0), ZEROIFNULL(expr)` could be used to change the result from NULL to 0.